# Code block in DispatchQueue.main.async is never getting executed

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sfauthorizationpluginview

I am working on a bundle project in swift which is used as an [authorization plugin](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/authorization_plug-ins/using_authorization_plug-ins) and in the bundle project I am doing API request call using `URLSession.shared.dataTask` and in the call back I receive, I am trying to update the UI and as updating UI has to be done using main thread I am using `DispatchQueue.main.async` and the code inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` is never getting executed! **This works perfectly fine in a normal MacOS Cocoa application but the problem persists with Bundle project for MacOS.**

**CODE:**

```
class MainForm: NSWindowController{

    public var bodyParams: [String: Any]?

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        testfetch{ (Response) in
            os_log("In completion handler response: %@", Response)
           //code to update some UI follows
        }
    }

    func testfetch(completion: @escaping (Response) -> ()){
        os_log("Is this mainthread in testFetch %@", Thread.isMainThread ? "Yes" : "No")
        os_log("Current thread testFetch %@", Thread.current)
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        bodyParams = ["username": "******", "password": "*****"]
        if let bodyParams = bodyParams {
            guard let body = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyParams, options: []) else {
                return
            }
            request.httpBody = body
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data else {
                    os_log("Data not recieved!!")
                    return
                }
                os_log("Is this mainthread in dataTask %@", Thread.isMainThread ? "Yes" : "No")
                os_log("Current thread in dataTask %@", Thread.current)
                os_log("Data recieved in testFetch: %@", String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                do{
                    let receivedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        os_log("Is this mainthread in main.async %@", Thread.isMainThread ? "Yes" : "No")
                        os_log("Current thread in main.async %@", Thread.current)
                        completion(receivedData)
                    }
                }
                catch let Err{
                    os_log("Error is: %@", Err as! String)
                }

            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    struct Response: Codable {
        let name, age, status: String
    }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
Is this mainthread in testFetch? Yes
Current thread testFetch <NSThread: 0x7f9176001c30>{number = 1, name = main}
Is this mainthread in dataTask No
Current thread in dataTask  <NSThread: 0x7f9173dc2080>{number = 4, name = (null)}
Data recieved in testFetch: {"name":"JohnDoe", "age": "**", "status": "single"}
```

So the logs in `DispatchQueue.main.async` and completion handler are never getting printed. I am quite new to swift and async programming any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `tempDropDownView`? When/where/how is `dropDownView` created? Is `prepareDropDownView` called?

Comment: Hi Willeke, sorry `tempDropDown` view is `dropDownView`  forgot to edit that while pasting code now I have updated it, and prepareDropDownView is called in `AppController.swift` in `handleAuthRequired` function which you can see it at bottom of the code.

Comment: Are `handleAuthRequired` and `prepareDropDownView` called at runtime?

Comment: Yes, `handleAuthRequired` is called in `handleStatus` API request completion handler and `prepareDropDownView` is called in `handleAuthRequired` and I am doing API request in `windowDidLoad` and after completion of request the `handleStatus` from `AppController` class gets called sending received API response as an argument and then in `handleStatus` function depending on the received response I am initialising the `dropDownView` in `prepareDropDownView` function from `MainWindow` class and this application is authorization plugin i.e a bundle project.

Comment: Is "Auth Required after API call!" printed?

Comment: No not printed at the start but I have a button on the window which is for debugging purpose and on click of this button I am setting authorization result to allow and login user and after clicking this button then "Auth Required after API call" is being printed!! and if I don't click on this login button it is not logging "Auth Required after API call". I even tried wrapping `handleStatus` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` but still no use, it is still same behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209829/discussion-between-mohit-and-willeke).

Comment: Hi @Willeke narrowed down the issue and updated the entire question, please see if you can help thanks.